What are the benefits of using the N prefix with VARCHAR instead of using NVARCHAR?
I can't find any resources that discuss this topic. I understand that NVARCHAR is used for non-English languages and takes up extra space, but why do some developers use a mix of the N prefix with the VARCHAR data type?
Could someone please guide me?

The  N prefix indicates Unicode strings - which only make sense with columns defined as  NVARCHAR. Using it with a VARCHAR  column is actually counter-productive, since SQL Server will need to implicitly convert back the Unicode string you've defined as a literal back to a regular, non-Unicode string, to store it in a VARCHAR column ...

for non-English languages what about emojis like ? Never mind English words like naïve or names like Charlotte Brontë

SQL Server supports two types of string literal

'foo' - A varchar string literal in the code page of the default collation of the current database (so for single byte collations supports whatever 256 characters that supports)
N'foo' - An nvarchar string literal.

So the case where an N prefix is useful in conjunction with varchar is when the literal contains a character not representable in the code page of the database's default collation but you are assigning it to a varchar that does have a collation that supports that character.
This is possibly particularly likely if you are using VARCHAR with UTF-8 collation.
For example (DB Fiddle)
 DECLARE @T TABLE(
    Col VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8 INDEX CIX CLUSTERED,
    NPrefix BIT NOT NULL);

INSERT @T VALUES ('普通话', 0),
                 (N'普通话',1);

SELECT *
FROM @T

Which for my Latin default collation results in



Col
NPrefix




???
0


普通话
1



You should be aware that using the N prefix for string literals in comparisons against varchar columns can be an anti pattern however. In some collations this can still be converted to an index seek in other collations the query plan ends up implicitly casting the column to nvarchar and this causes a scan.
In such column to literal comparisons where the string will not be correctly represented as a varchar string literal it is best to explicitly cast the literal as below (using same datatype and collation specification as the column) to get a simple index seek plan.
SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE Col = CAST(N'普通话' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8 AS VARCHAR(20))

